# My ASP.NET application is not working on the server, but it works in my development environment. 

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET application is not working on the server, but it works in my development environment.

How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: do you have some examples? what are the differences between your local computer environment and the server environment as far as configuration?

Comment: This is very generic question, would be nice if you could explain exact issue to narrow it down.

Comment: I think you are accessing the third party DLL and EXE in your local machine. like FFMPEG Video cutter or URL re-writing etc.. it will not work on server till it is shared or not having rights. you must have rights on server to accessing third party codes.

Comment: There could be a million things causing this but unless you provide some kind of information or exception that is thrown we will just be guessing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, when posting such a question to stackoverflow, **post as many details as possible**. These people on this site are brilliant and can fix your problem in a snap if you provide them enough information.

1. Confirm that you have deployed ALL dll, aspx, ascx, .vb, .cs, exe, image, and config files.
2. Confirm that you have deployed ALL folders
3. Confirm that your web.config has a valid connection string
4. Confirm that your entire folder tree has read/write permissions for network service account. (this can be backed down later)
5. Confirm that your entire folder tree has read permissions on the IUsr account
6. Confirm that your application pool (IIS Manager) has the same .NET Framework as your application was compiled in.  It's probably .NET Framework 4.0, but might be 3.5 or 2.0
7. Confirm that the web server has port 80 and 443 open in its firewall
8. Confirm that asp.net is installed on the web server

   - Navigation to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` in the command line and run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` if you need to reinstall asp.net 4.0. Sometimes this fixes problems.
9. Confirm that the web server serves up an html file. Add a file called test.htm to the root folder, and only include "Hello, I am test.htm" as its contents. Attempt to visit this in a browser. If it does not load, check permissions again.
10. Confirm that you have a dll on the server for every custom reference that you have added to your project, and confirm that the dlls are at an accessible path to the deployed web application (like, sitting in the bin folder)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as the person that post the question. I my development machine it runs smoothly. Deploying it in my own development machine opens the website bu gives me different w3wp.exe codes when opening a specific page inside my website.
I t seems it is a memory problem. I have tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.
The page that I am trying to open in has different linq queries.
I answer as much as I could from your questions.
Confirm that you have deployed ALL dll, aspx, ascx, .vb, .cs, exe, image, and config files.
Yes

1. Confirm that you have deployed ALL folders
   Yes
2. Confirm that your web.config has a valid connection string
   Yes
3. Confirm that your entire folder tree has read/write permissions for network service account. (this can be backed down later)
4. Confirm that your entire folder tree has read permissions on the IUsr account
5. Confirm that your application pool (IIS Manager) has the same .NET Framework as your application was compiled in. It's probably .NET Framework 4.0, but might be 3.5 or 2.0
   Yes 4.0
6. Confirm that the web server has port 80 and 443 open in its firewall
7. Confirm that asp.net is installed on the web server
   •   Navigation to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 in the command line and run aspnet_regiis.exe -i if you need to reinstall asp.net 4.0. Sometimes this fixes problems.
8. Confirm that the web server serves up an html file. Add a file called test.htm to the root folder, and only include "Hello, I am test.htm" as its contents. Attempt to visit this in a browser. If it does not load, check permissions again.
9. Confirm that you have a dll on the server for every custom reference that you have added to your project, and confirm that the dlls are at an accessible path to the deployed web application (like, sitting in the bin folder)